# memcache, wamp, php 5.4, win8

Tags: php, memcached

I am using `wamp`, `PHP 5.4` running on `win 8`,
I can't seem to get `PHP` to acknowledge the `memcache` `dll`.

I download `php_memcache-3.0.8-5.4-ts-vc9-x86.zip` (the only one I could find).

I copied the `dll` to `C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.4.12\ext`

I added `extension=php_memcache.dll`

restart the server.

but still I cannot use `memcache`, and it is missing from `Loaded Extensions` list.

Please supply a step-by-step instruction on how to set this up,

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You have to install memcached as well.

php_memcached is only an interface to the memcached service that also has to be running on the system your Apache/PHP is running on.

[This site seems to be offering a ready to go .exe](http://blog.couchbase.com/memcached-144-windows-32-bit-binary-now-available)

[This may also help with getting it running](http://zurmo.org/wiki/installing-memcache-on-windows)